# load network-based images asynchronously in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, asynchronous, loading

I have to be able to load and draw X amount of images located on a network based drive.
I need help finding a way to load the images asynchronously.

```
 java.net.URL Loc = new URL("http://auroragm.sourceforge.net/GameCover/GameCases/Mass-Effect.png");
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
    lbl.setIcon((anotherIcon = new ImageIcon(Loc)));
```

The above is one image which loads on the GUI thread and thus would freeze if 20 more were to be loaded. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Thread could be helpful and you could limit the number of threads run same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the images in separate thread. Please treat below code as pseudo-code:

```
final java.net.URL Loc = new URL("http://.../Mass-Effect.png");
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Object content = Loc.getContent();
        // content would be probably some Image class or byte[]

        // or:
        // InputStream in = Loc.openStream();
        // read image from in
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you should load the images on another thread.

Swing does provide a nice set of classes & patterns for this:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html